# get old value back into the first textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two textboxes and i don't want to use third one for showing the result.
The scenario is that textbox1 is `totalFeetextbox` and textBox2 is `DiscountTextBox`.
I want the user to enter amount in `discountTextBox` and see the result in `TotalFeeTextBox` and when the user removes the amount, the `TotalFeeTextbox` should show the original amount i.e. the old one before the calculation.

This is one of the codes i tried on textChanged event:

```
try 
{
    String tempStore = TotalFeeTextBox.Text;

    if (DiscountTextBox.Text.Length != 0) 
    {
        TotalFeeTextBox.Text = (TotalFeeTextBox.Text - DiscountTextBox.Text).toSting();
    }
    else
    {
        TotalFeeTextBox.Text = tempStore;
    }
} 
catch (ApplicationException ex) 
{
    //Catch error if one is still thrown after above code; Not pretty, exceptions are costly performance wise.
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex.Message, "ERROR");
}
```

Is there anyway to get it done what I stated above?

Comment: Store tempstore from a different scope so it is only set one time.

Comment: Not related: remove `try ... catch`. You want get all possible information about exception if such will be thrown. Showing message will not help, because it didn't tell you line and hide StackTrace

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written has a few problems. First you treat string as number and second you use text boxes to store values. You should use variables for that. The code below will be close to what you need.

First add two properties and fill them with your required values

```
float total;
float discount;
```

Then you handle the event for text change in `DiscountTextBox` with a function like below

```
private void DiscountTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DiscountTextBox.Text))
    {
        discount = float.Parse(DiscountTextBox.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        discount = 0;
    }

    TotalFeeTextBox.Text = (total - discount).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Still Same Issue. TotalFeeTextBox not showing the original value if discountTextBox is cleared and also calculation is wrong if i try to correct amount.

Comment: See the edit. If you need more information you might need to post some more code for me to see how it's structured.